# What filter size and lens hoods do I need for my Nikon 18-55mm and 55-200mm lenses?

Tags: lens, nikon, accessories

What size UV filter, lens hood, and lens cap do I need for my Nikon AF-S DX 18-55mm VR II and AF-S DX 55-200mm VR II lenses?

Comment: Required reading: [Do I need a UV filter?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/67252/do-i-need-a-uv-filter) and the questions linked from there.

Comment: For everything but the lens hood, see [How do I find the right size of filters for a lens?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/10864/how-do-i-find-the-right-size-of-filters-for-a-lens)

Answer (score 5):

Everything you need to know you can find at Nikon's site for each of those lenses.

[AF-S DX NIKKOR 18-55mm f/3.5-5.6G VR II](http://www.nikonusa.com/en/nikon-products/product/camera-lenses/af-s-dx-nikkor-18-55mm-f%252f3.5-5.6g-vr-ii.html#tab-ProductDetail-ProductTabs-TechSpecs)

- Filter size: 52mm (same for lens cap)
- Hood: [HB-69 Bayonet Lens Hood](http://www.nikonusa.com/en/nikon-products/product/lens-hoods/hb-69-bayonet-lens-hood.html)

[AF-S DX NIKKOR 55-200mm f/4-5.6G ED VR II](http://www.nikonusa.com/en/nikon-products/product/camera-lenses/af-s-dx-nikkor-55-200mm-f%252f4-5.6g-ed-vr-ii.html#tab-ProductDetail-ProductTabs-TechSpecs)

- Filter size: 52mm (same for lens cap)
- Hood: [HB-37 Bayonet Lens Hood](http://www.nikonusa.com/en/nikon-products/product/lens-hoods/hb-37-bayonet-lens-hood.html)

Answer (score 2):

Your 18-55mm Nikon kit lens has 52mm threads (at least the current version of the Nikon 18-55mm kit lens does). This should be indicated on the front of the lens by a mark that looks something like this: Ø52

Your 55-250mm lens probably also has 52mm threads. This should be indicated by a mark on the front of the lens that looks like: Ø52. I have found some online references to some versions of a Nikon 55-200 with 55mm and 58mm threads. But whatever is printed on the front of the lens next to the "Ø" mark is the thread size in millimeters. If you can't find such a mark on the front of the lens (or on the barrel near the front for some lenses) you can look on the back side of the lens cap that fits the lens. They often have the size marked as either 52mm or Ø52.

You can always use an accessory that has larger filter size threads with a smaller filter thread size lens by using a step up ring. The smaller threads on the back of the ring screw into the threads on the front of your lens. The larger threads inside the outer rim of the ring then receive the threads of your filters.

Answer (score 2):

A cautionary note to others to prevent them making the same mistake I did:

The newer version of this lens (AF-P instead of AF-S) uses a 55mm filter, not a 52mm.

Answer (score 1):

First, prefer using a lens hood than a UV filter. You should not need a filter unless in the presence of salt water splashing, flying sand or similar.

Second, a lens hood must match the lens, not just to account for its size but also its optical design. An 18-55mm and a 55-200mm may have the same diameter for the hood-mounting bayonet but a hood for the 55-200mm will severely impair an 18-55mm lens. You need to find the exact part numbers from Nikon.

For the filter thread, things are simpler. Both those lens support 52mm filters. In general though, it is highly recommended to get a larger more universal size and use step-up-rings. That way you don't need to buy new filters each time you get a larger lenses. Now, it seems 82mm is a safe choice but, for historic reasons, I use 77mm and 62mm as universal sizes for med-size and small-size lenses, respectively. The catch though is that you cannot use a lens hood and filter with step-ring at the same time.

Lens caps should match the thread since you need one for each lens anyways. So 52mm. Those are *almost* universal, so there are third-party ones which can be had for cheap.

Comment: you should probably note the con of using larger filters: can't be used in conjunction with the hood.