# Nikon Lens Cover

Tags: lens, nikon

I have an AF-S Nikkor 18-140mm 1:3.5-5.6 G ED lens. I have lost the cap. Wikipedia says the lens diameter is 69mm. I cannot find a 69mm cap online. The best I can do is 67mm. Can anybody shed any light on this. Thanks. I would like to buy one soon.

Comment: Related: [What filter size and lens hoods do I need for my Nikon 18-55mm and 55-200mm lenses?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/80337/15871)

Answer (score 1):

The filter size is what you need to know, which for that lens is 67mm.

The Nikon brand lens cap is the 67 mm snap-on Front Lens Cap LC-67.

http://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/lens/zoom/normalzoom/af-s_dx_18-140mmf_35-56g_ed_vr/