# Could a filter damage the curved front element of the Canon EF 100mm f/2.8 Macro USM?

Tags: lens, canon, filters, equipment-damage

I just got the Canon EF 100mm f/2.8 Macro USM and I really want to put a UV filter on the lens to protect the front element, but I feel uneasy screwing one on because of the curved front element. I feel that if I screw in the filter all the way, the front element will rub against the filter and will scratch or at the very least put unecessary pressure on the glass.

The filter I have is Tiffen 58mm that I used previously with my kit lens.

I tried to put a small piece of tissue in the center of the filter and then screwed it on and it seems that the tissue is getting depressed :S I really want to love this lens, but why couldnt they just make the filter thread sticking out further?

Has anyone else experienced issues with filters for this lens?

What about  ultra thin filters? Would that help anyway or do they have the same thread depth? Never used one before.

Comment: I don't think Canon will design a lens and then put the filter threads in such a position that you have to damage your lens to use it. Not on purpose at least, and I think Canon designers are quite smart. I wouldn't worry too much.

Comment: If you get to prove that the filter touches the lens, you can get the ring out of a somewhat cheap filter and remove the glass, and use that ring between your lens and the filter. Just watch out for vignettes!

Comment: @jahaziel great suggestion! Any ideas how I can safely check if the filter touches the glass?

Comment: If you want to know if it touches, use a hair.  Tissue is relatively thick.

Comment: @Rado My Idea: put your filter on a table, lens side up and pour a drop of lens cleaning fluid in the center. Then screw the lens into the filter without taking it off the table (both must be completely dust free to avoid any damage). Unscrew the lens and observe if the lens is wet. If it is, the filter is too close. Wipe the lens an then the filter with lens cleaning tissue or a quality microfiber cloth.

Comment: @Jahaziel Can you put your comments as an answer? I'd like to accept them as the answer. Thanks

Comment: Before using a UV filter just for protection, you may want to consider http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1393/is-a-uv-filter-better-for-lens-protection-than-a-protector-filter http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/57/are-there-any-downsides-to-using-a-good-quality-uv-filter and http://www.lensrentals.com/blog/2008/10/front-element-scratches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be a chance where certain lens-filter combination can result in the filter touching the surface of the lens. Even if they do not actually make contact, the gap can get to be so small that some dust particle could get squeezed in between and cause damage.

I suggest the following to find if the filter gets too close to the lens:
Put your filter on a table, lens side up and pour a drop of lens cleaning fluid in the center. Then screw the lens into the filter without taking it off the table (both must be completely dust free to avoid any damage). Unscrew the lens and observe if the lens is wet. If it is, the filter is too close. Wipe the lens an then the filter with lens cleaning tissue or a quality microfiber cloth.

If you get to prove that the filter touches the lens (or simply want to make sure you wont get any damage from it), you can get the ring out of a somewhat cheap filter and remove the glass, and use that ring between your lens and the filter. Just watch out for vignettes!

Answer (score 2):

Canon wouldn't give the lens filter threads if it couldn't take filters.  All the literature about the lens indicates it accepts 58mm filters, so it will be fine.

[Here is a product compatibility list](http://usa.canon.com/cusa/consumer/products/cameras/slr_cameras/modelSNACompatibles.action?accessoryCid=0901e024802850e2&accessoryModelName=58mm%20Filter%20UV%20Protector) for their 58mm UV filter, where the  EF 100mm f/2.8 Macro USM is listed.

Ultra thin filters wouldn't make any difference.  In fact, since there is less thickness supporting the glass, they would be even closer to the lens.

Comment: I'm aware that 58mm filters should fit on the lens, but I think that maybe the Tiffen filter I have might have deeper thread than canons