# Good quality UV Filter

Tags: filters, accessories, uv

I recently bought the nikon 50mm 1.8 af-s lens. I bought a uv filter for it. It was a "multi-coated" filter, but when I put it on, the first thing I noticed was that it causes reflections. I returned it. Now I'm wondering what is a good UV filter for this lens?

Comment: Why do you want a UV filter?

Comment: Just for lens protection

Comment: See also: [Is a UV Filter required/recommended for lens protection?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/17854/is-a-uv-filter-required-recommended-for-lens-protection)

Comment: I use a UV filter for lens protection that I screw off before taking pictures. When I'm done I use a rocket blower to blow dirt and dust off the lens before putting the filter back on. In cold conditions, bone dry cold air is trapped between the lens and the filter which will prevent moisture from condensing on the lens when I'm back home.

Comment: Also related: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/39879/will-a-filter-cause-more-or-less-damage-when-lens-is-dropped/39894#39894 Just because a filter shatters doesn't mean the much thicker and harder front element of the lens would have suffered the same fate had the filter not been there.

Comment: True. But I'm also concerned about scratches. It's much easier to replace the filter if it gets scratched than the lens if it gets scratched.

Comment: See also http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/50633/how-to-clean-shattered-uv-filter-glass-from-lens/50635#50635 In certain situations a shattered filter will incease the risk of scratches.

Comment: Front element scratches have very little impact on the image quality of a lens. It takes a LOT to make a detectable difference. See also http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/71569/how-can-i-remove-scratches-from-a-lens/71573#71573 and this link form that answer: http://www.lensrentals.com/blog/2008/10/front-element-scratches/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't have it yet, get the original lens hood. It will protect the lens and **improve** image quality.

Comment: I do have it. I always use hoods.

Comment: I think as long as I do use the hood I should be ok without it for now

Answer (score 2):

My advice is, never mount a filter unless the harm overshadows the good. Besides the digital camera sports an internal UV filter built into the protective cover glass that protects the image sensor. Yes, some filters are better than others. Generally you get what you pay for.

A UV filter prevents most ultraviolet rays from entering the camera. The UV filter was a must if you were doing aerial photography and/or imaging a distance mountain landscape etc. When shooting with film. A UV filter has the ability to cut through haze caused by the scattering of UV light in the earth’s atmosphere. The UV filter will not enhance nearby subjects. The chief reason we mount a UV filter is to guard our valued lenses from scratches and abrasions. When we mount any filter, we are adding two extra surfaces of polished glass and these add to the percentage of light lost. An uncoated filter will reflect about 5% and a coated filter will reflect about 2%. Some of this reflected light from the back surface enters the camera as wandering rays and these add flare and ghost images. Now different colors have different wavelengths and each can be mitigated by multi-coating. It is the thickness of the coat that counts. Each color needs a unique coat thickness.