# How do I find the right size of filters for a lens?

Tags: lens, filters

I was looking to get a circular polarizing filter and an UV filter for my Canon 550D, 18-135mm lens. When I checked online I found these filters came in different sizes, like 62mm, 67mm, 72mm, 77mm. How do I know which is right?

Also, will there be any degradation of photo quality if I put both these filters on the lens?

Comment: Hi sfactor! No need to apologize for lack of knowledge. This is a Q/A site, so we're all hoping to learn. As for the degradation of quality issue, see this question: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/57/are-there-any-downsides-to-using-a-uv-filter

Comment: @mattdm +1 for kindness and sheer coherence. Anyway, while it must be appreciated that it offers many different points of view, I think the question you linked to shows the typical bias we were talking about in meta. @sfactor you will hardly need to use both filters at the same time, and you should avoid that.

Comment: Many older lenses do not have markings for the filter size (like old Nikon Nikkor lenses).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As per other answers, it is usually **marked with the ⌀ symbol** on the front and, if not, on the barrel. Some specialty lenses do not accept filters, in which case you won't find any markings.

**For your lens, [the thread is 67mm](http://www.neocamera.com/lens.php?id=169)**

This is the thread size which means you can **attach that size of filter directly**. This convenient but costly. Instead, I buy my filters in the largest size (77mm usually) and have **step-up rings to bridge the gap**. A step-up ring costs about $12, so if you buy 77mm filters and have a 58mm, 67mm and 77mm lens, you need 2 step-up rings: 58->77 and 67->77. The only catch that you can't use a step-up ring and a lens hood at the same time. **It saves lots of money considering a good polarizer costs over $200.** Even if you have just two lenses with different filters you'll save. My lenses have 8 filter sizes so you can imaging how much money I saved on polarizers alone!

**There will be a degradation in image quality if you use a filter.** [See my answer to this question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/10616/does-custom-white-balance-cancel-out-the-pink-of-skylight-filter/10621#10621). Generally, the less you pay, the more degradation there will be. UV filters are usually sold for protection but polarizers have a genuinely useful photographic purpose, attenuating glare, surface reflections and increasing color saturation of the sky and some other surfaces as a side-effect.

Comment: +1 for noting the use of step-down filters.  BTW, a *great* polarizer doesn't have to cost $200 (although some do).  In objective tests the Marumi filters tend to perform as well as the top-price ones but cost only 1/2 to 1/3 as much.

Comment: Although it should be ⌀ — http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2300/index.htm :)

Comment: You can also get unwanted vignetting if you stack up multiple lenses!!!  I found this out the hard way after taking around 50 photos with the UV filter and the Polarizer on.  Had to go back and retake all the photos will just the Polarizer.

Comment: @JohnBubriski: Yes, and the same thing applies to filter + step-up ring combos. However, it's generally only an issue with wide angle lenses. Roughly 24mm and wider, I'd say. With a *really* wide angle lens, you may have to be careful to get un-stackable filters, the sort that only let you put a single filter on the lens at a time, because the extra set of *threads* can cause vignetting!

Answer (score 8):

Take a look at the business end of the lens, i.e the end you point at subjects. Around the outside of the glass is a plastic bit where it says 'Canon Zoom Lens 18-135mm' etc.

Somewhere on there will be a symbol - a circle with a line through it, followed by a number. In the case of your 18-135mm, it should say 67mm.

Answer (score 4):

The filter size is usually printed on the lens. If you look at the front of it, it's usually either just inside the edge before the glass (which I think is the case for your lens) or just along the outside of it. I suspect it's 67mm, but you should confirm it. It will have what looks like an O with a vertical line through it (Greek phi), followed by the size in mm. Something like Φ67mm is what you want to find.

Matt linked to an answer about UV filters in terms of effect. In general, the more glass you put in front of the image sensor, the more you impact the image quality. However, this can often be undetectable and acceptable for the gains that a particular filter may provide in other ways. For example, a polarizer may allow you to get a shot that you might not otherwise, so if there is a loss of image quality, you'd accept it. Having said all that, it's not really an issue for the most part. The only thing to be aware of is that polarizer will reduce the light by a couple of stops.

Comment: Although it's not actually phi, it's the engineering symbol for diameter :)

Comment: It looks like it... Close enough for government work. :)

Comment: It's that kind of shoddy thinking that's got the world in its current mess! ;)

Comment: good answer. To be picky: "...reduce the light by a couple of stops" **citation needed**. In past years I often used a cokin polarizer on a Panasonic Lumix FZ8 and I found out the meter never showed any difference. I mention this to say that's the only context I used a polarizer in, it could be different with another (better) camera/lens. The FZ8's sensor sucks compared to newer ones, but the camera as a whole is an excellent compact. This leads me to believe it didn't get fooled by the filter and a polarizer actually didn't affect how much light came in.

Comment: @Mattia - The job of the polarizer is to absorb certain polarized light so it can't but reduce the amount of light coming through.

Comment: @Mattia - Here's my citation *'polarizers reduce light by between 2 and 2 1/2 stops'*. I can put it my website to make it official ;) If the meter does not change, your images would come out quite dark. Perhaps if Auto ISO was on, then you did not notice the camera compensating.

Comment: @Itai nah, only ISO 100 had decent quality on that camera. I looked for examples because I couldn't believe the difference was so big and I found out two silly yet appropriate shots [this one](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/23492662/P1070221.JPG) and [this one](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/23492662/P1070220.JPG). They actually differ by one stop, which is a bit in favor of and a bit more against my statement :-)

Comment: If you pass unpolarized light through a perfect polarizing filter, the intensity will be reduced by half (1 stop). If you're using it to deliberately suppress light that's preferentially polarized (e.g. reflections, or sky 90 degrees from sun) the loss will be somewhat more. And real polarizers aren't perfect, and tend to have a little extra light loss.

Comment: @coneslayer - Did the test today. Circular polarizer, 2 stops loss. Multi-Coated circular polarizer, 2 stops loss. Super Multi-Coated circular polarizer, 2 stops loss. Circular HD polarizer, 1 stop loss (yes, I own one of each, time to sell a few!). I always *knew* it was 2 stops, only I had not checked with the HD one. That is a lesson for me to refresh my knowledge often.

Comment: @Itai Where you experimenting with highly polarized light or virtually non-polarized light? The difference between the two might astound you.

Comment: @MichaelClark - It's been a while but I'm pretty sure it was non-polarized light. That represents the general loss of stops. Obviously polarized light would have been a useful measure too, put of efficiency at polarization and would be highly dependent on the filter rotation.

Answer (score 2):

Your question about diameter has already been answered I see. As for the stacking question, stacking filters should be avoided unless absolutely necessary. Each filter adds two new surfaces that can be dirty and/or scratched, which is a bad thing. Each filter also adds two new surfaces which can cause flare and reflections, which is a worse thing.

As a general principle, ditch the UV filter. It serves absolutely no photographic purpose on a digital camera. It gives some small measure of protection for the front element, but so does a lens-hood which in addition does serve a photographic purpose by reducing flare. Add a filter only when you need to - the only ones you need to, largely speaking, are polarizing filters and neutral gray filters.

Answer (score 0):

No matter what filter size you use, you always want to put the polarizing filter on last.  The end of the polarizing filter rotates so that you can filter the light from any direction (or camera orientation), so you don't want to have anything on the end of that.

I'm not even sure if my polarizing filter (B+W) has threads to accept additional filters stacked on top now that I think about it.

Answer (score 0):

Check the inside of the lens cap, it should have the filter diameter.

If you put both the filters on the lens, you may get black corners on your images at 18 mm.