# How to decide which reversing ring is suitable for a lens?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, nikon, reverse-mount

Nikon's website doesn't seem to suggest any reversing rings that go with specific lenses (in my case a 50mm f/1.8G) .

For macro shots how to decide which reversing ring goes with it?
Yeah, Amazon shows lots of results, but on which basis should I decide what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You base a reversing ring on the filter thread size and mount for your camera.  To determine your size, check [this question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/10864/how-do-i-find-the-right-size-of-filters-for-a-lens).
That particular lens has a 58mm filter size, so you need something like [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001G4LOGS) that uses the Nikon mount.

---

<sub>I'm assuming you mean the 50mm f/1.8 **G** and not the **D**, since your D3100 won't autofocus with the D but will with the G.  If you mean the D version, its 52mm.</sub>

Comment: @Anisha - Actually, you didn't, I edited it in.

Comment: Okay here is an apology - a big one.

Comment: @Anisha lol, no worries.  Hope your D3100 is treating you nice, post some pics in chat to share!

Comment: Rfusca, see what Nikon has. http://www.nikon.co.in/en_IN/product_details.page?DCRPath=templatedata/en_IN/saleable_product_information/data/Accessories/Nikkor%20Lenses/Close-up%20Accessories/Macro%20Adapter%20Ring%20BR-5.xml&CategoryID=gp11zl02&currentTab=&currentLink=gp11zl17 Which one among them is a "reversing" ring?

Comment: @Anisha it doesn't look like Nikon has an official one for the 58mm size.  I wouldn't hesitate using a well known 3rd party product for this though - its just a solid piece of metal.

Comment: Hey Rfusca, do you have a website somewhere- Can I see your photos? You are on facebook or 500px.com?

Comment: @Anisha - I don't have much public.  Most of what I do these days is family or clients.