# What size adapter ring do I need to mount the Cokin P Series filter holder on my lens?

Tags: filters, filter-diameter, cokin

I have an Olympus E-510 with the 14–45mm lens. I am interested in buying the [Cokin P Series Gradual ND Filter Kit with Holder](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Cokin-Gradual-Filter-Kit-Holder/dp/B01HMWKUBW), but it does not say for which lenses it is suitable.

Is it going to be alright or it needs a ring? And if yes which diameter?

Comment: Is this suppose to be ok? https://www.amazon.co.uk/digiCAP-Objective-Filter-58-Adapter/dp/B006DEM7OE/ref=sr_1_fkmr0_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1498294145&sr=8-1-fkmr0&keywords=DigiCap+Set+Up+Adapter+58+Mm+Filter+To+52+Mm+Lens

Comment: @inkista They're closely related though. But since you mentioned it, I can't find an appropriate dupe. I agree, and have retracted.

Comment: Related: [How do I find the right size of filters for a lens?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/10864)

Answer (score 3):

As the advert says...

> "Everything you need to get started, apart from adapter ring specific
>   to your lens diameter."

Google tells me that lens has a 58mm thread, indicated by the ⌀58 on the front.
[Double check that my info is correct before ordering.]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is just me, but if you're buying everything new and not adapting an existing set of filters, I think going with Cokin P series is overkill unless you're getting a supertelephoto zoom. You can probably get away with the series A adapter.

The P filters are designed for lenses with a maximum size of 82mm. The A series maximum size is 62mm. The biggest filter ring I've run into on an MFT lens is 58mm. You may still need a step-up ring to use the adapter ring with a particularly small lens, like the m.Zuiko 45/1.8 which is Ø37mm, or if you want to avoid buying multiple Cokin adapter rings.

And the adapter ring is a Cokin adapter ring for the specific series that will fit on the front of your lens, it's not just a step-up ring, but has a flange onto which the holder slots. B&H lists the Series A adapter rings [here](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/buy/cokin/Ntt/cokin+A+series+adapter+ring/N/0). If you want to put it directly on your 14-42, then get a 58mm sized one, since that's the size filter thread it takes.

See also: B&H's ["The Cokin Creative Filter System"](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/explora/photography/hands-review/cokin-creative-filter-system) page.