# Vignetting after using circular polarizer and cokin system

Tags: nikon, filters, polarizer, vignetting, cokin

I have Nikon D750 camera with a lens having a focal length from 24-70mm and lens diameter 72mm. I have bought a circular polarizer and Cokin P system filters with a wide-angle filter holder. But there is some vignetting at 24mm. What system should I buy to remove vignetting? Is the P system small and I should go with XL? [image: Cokin system with circular polarizer]

[image: Cokin system without polarizer]

First photo is with cokin filter and circular polarizer
and second photo is cokin filter without circular polarizer

Comment: [Relevant answer to other question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/90391/9161), it seems the P system goes up to 82mm lens diameters. The size should not be an issue for you, but I wouldn't know what would then be causing the vignetting. Perhaps you can add some pictures of your camera + filter and the resulting images?

Comment: I added some images. I think vignetting is due to the circular polarizer.

Answer (score 1):

Is the vignetting happening in the sky when using the lens at 24mm?

In that case the issue is simply that a polarizing filter produces an uneven effect on wide angles.

Update: Just as I added this answer, you posted images that shows that this is not the cause of the issue.

Comment: This is my first time with the filters, so I am not sure if I bought the right one or not.

Comment: If the filter is not close to the lens, e.g. you're using an adapter ring, that increases vignetting.