# Which adapter to mount Yashica adaptor lenses on a SIGMA SA-7?

Tags: sigma, adapter

I own SIGMA SA-7 and a couple of YASHICA  lenses: YAHICOR Y503 Telephoto and YASHICA Y504 wide lens, both seem to be 55 mm wide. I would like to use them with  my SIGMA  original lenses, 70-300 and 28-80. I need an adapter but I do not know what brand and exact size. What kind of adapter do I need?

Comment: What are the filter thread sizes of your 28-80mm and 70-300mm lenses?

Comment: Do you know if the Yashica lenses are for an SLR (C/Y mount) or a rangefinder?

Comment: @inkista The Yashica "lenses" mentioned are screw on "adapters" placed on the front of another lens.

Comment: The filter thread size, measured inside the ring, seems to be 55-56 mm.

Comment: The Yashica lenses are rather for SLR

Comment: No, they (Yashica lenses) cannot be placed directly in front of SIGMA 28-80 mm and 70-300 mm lenses because there is a need for an adapter.That is exactly what I try to figure out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use lens brand X on interchangeable lens camera brand Y?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/62000/can-i-use-lens-brand-x-on-interchangeable-lens-camera-brand-y)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find the right size of filters for a lens?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/10864/how-do-i-find-the-right-size-of-filters-for-a-lens)

Answer (score 2):

You have not provided enough information (pictures) to identify the mounts on your lenses.

- The "lenses" you mention appear to be **conversion lenses** that screw onto the filter threads of other *real* lenses. Look for a symbol that looks like a circle with a line crossed through it (∅) on the lens you wish to use them with. The number following the symbol is the filter size of the lens in millimeters. You will need a step-up or step-down ring from that size to the size of the conversion lenses, which you have indicated is 55mm.

  Such conversion lenses are essentially toys that significantly degrade the quality of the image. They cannot even be given away for the price of shipping. You are better off seeking better *real* lenses for your camera.
- If the Yashica lenses you describe are *not* conversion lenses, **there is likely no existing adapter to use them on Sigma SA mount** because the SA mount is not popular enough. Only two adapters are returned when searching a popular auction site for SA mount adapters:

  - M42-SA adapter
  - Hasselblad V-SA tilt-shift adapter

  Neither appears suitable for Yashica lenses.