# What causes these green dots in my image?

Tags: filters, low-light, artifacts, lens-flare, fast-lenses

I just received a [35mm f/1.8 DX](http://www.kenrockwell.com/nikon/35mm-f18.htm) lens for my [Nikon D50](http://www.kenrockwell.com/nikon/d50.htm) for Christmas, and took some shots where the lights on the tree were the main source of illumination.  Almost all of them exhibit very prominent green after-images of the tree lights.  For example, in this image they run from the left side of the mirror down to the left side of the fireplace:

[image: Tree with green lights]

Are these artifacts caused by the lens, the camera, the filter (a Tiffen 52mm UV protector), or a combination of them?  How can I avoid them in future shots?

Comment: Try removing the UV filter, it might generate the lens flares.

Comment: omg!! aliens!! :O

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The UV filter likely explains this.

As I've explained in [this answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/17854/is-a-uv-filter-required-recommended-for-lens-protection/25666#25666), *any* filter will degrade image quality, but some do so more than others.  Tiffen filters do not have anti-reflective coatings and are thus prone to flare.  You should either remove the filter or use a high-quality one from a brand like B+W or Hoya.

Answer (score 14):

Those are almost certainly reflections from the UV filter. I recommend taking it off.

This is a topic of much debate, but the fact is filters do cause artifacts visible in your photos — you've got the evidence right there. You can get better results from a more expensive filter, but then it'll cost almost as much as your lens. Lenses aren't as fragile as they seem. Just be careful, use a lens hood, and put the lens cap on when you're not shooting.

Comment: Just try the same shot with the UV filter removed. If it fixes the next shots, you know it was the cause.

You avoid problems caused by a UV filter by using a lens hood instead.

Comment: The green dots... looks like the Christmas tree is being reflected back :D

Comment: @Peng — Yes. The lights from the Christmas tree bounced by the filter.

Comment: I add, "except at the beach".  Weigh the risk as well as the cost of a lens.

Answer (score 2):

it's definitely the filter, even my 30 dollar hoya does this in low light, it really screwed up some pics before.