# how can i avoid red flare on my sun set photos?

Tags: nikon, dslr, filters, uv

[image]

I have used a lense filter. Still some red spot appeared in my click.Please help me to sort out this problem. Thankew.

Comment: What type of filter did you use? A graduated ND filter or a polarizer? Or a UV filter because you believe it provides your lens with "protection?"

Answer (score 3):

This looks like ghosting or other flare caused by a reflection off the back of a lens element or filter. Flat filters are often the most obvious offenders.

If you are using a UV filter for "protection"¹, remove the filter. If you are using a graduated ND filter or a polarizer, you must weigh the benefits of the filter versus the benefit of not having a reflection.

<sub>¹ For a thorough look at the disadvantages/advantages of using UV filters for "protection," please see [this answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/90197/15871) to [is uv filter a must?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/90191/15871)</sub>