# Prevent ghosting of sun at sunrise

Tags: reflection, sun

I took picture of sunrise in the mountain and the sun appear inside the mountain.

[image: Pointe Percée - Aravis - French alps - taken from roc Lancrenaz]

What the name of this effect? is this ghosting due to high luminosity? how can I prevent it ?

My setting was :

- **camera** : Nikon D750
- **lens** : 85mm f/1.8D
- **ISO** : 320
- **aperture** : f/11
- **speed** : 1/2000
- UV filter with lens hood on

As suggested by [this answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/35054/92254) is it related to the fact that I have a UV filter on ?

---

The mountain name is "Pointe Percée" from the Aravis in the French Alps taken from "roc Lancrenaz".

Full image :

[image: Pointe Percée / Aravis / French Alps taken from roc Lancrenaz]

Comment: Great shot anyway, IMO.

Comment: [To filter or not to filter, that is the question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/90197/15871)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a perfect answer, but in my view it's almost impossible to prevent such effects, as even the best lens optics can have issues with such extremes of brightness and ghosting.

So I use editing where possible to fix things like this.  Failing that you need to choose lenses very, very carefully and avoid filters as much as possible so that you're not risking introducing problems.

In this specific case it's a relatively easy correction in editing.  I used GIMP and the G'MIC plugin's "Repairs -> Inpaint [Transport Diffusion]" filter and a quick repair brush tidy up and it was done in all seconds.  Here's the result :

[image]

Comment: Do you think a bigger hood could reduce this effect ? or only a better lens without filter may help ?

Comment: A hood cannot hurt, but is mainly for shading the lens from strong light sources *outside* the field of view (which can still cause flare/ghosting).  I doubt it would help this specific case, but my recommendation is *always* shoot with the hood - it's part of the optical design of the lens.  Filters - never use them unless there are very specific reasons requiring protection or a specific optical effect, like a polarizer.  UV filters for protection is a subject that causes major arguments - I'm in the "worse than useless" camp, some people are in the "never shoot without one".

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not ghosting, but uncontrolled flare. When used right, it's actually a nice creative quirk.

Tried shooting it it only with a CPL filter? Depending on lens/angle/ quality of UV filter, you could get all sorts of weird reflections *inside* your optics that could cause this.

Comment: Can't see a useful purpose for a CPL here and it could cause just as many problems.  Just internal reflection from even the best lens could cause issues like these - adding more optics doesn't help, IMO.

Comment: To amplify @StephenG's comment: A polarizer does almost zilch when the sun is straight on to the lens. Of course the back of a polarizer is just as flat as an UV/protective filter with all of the issues that can cause.