# Which is the correct filter size for Canon SX30 IS?

Tags: filters, uv, canon-sx30

I bought the Canon SX30is last week. I want to buy a filter for that. Can you suggest to me which is the better filter for that?

I read lots of reviews on that — there is confusion about 52mm UV filters directly attached on lens and 67mm with an adaptor.

Which should I buy?

Comment: See also http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/57/are-there-any-downsides-to-using-a-uv-filter, "Are there any downsides to using a UV filter?"

Answer (score 4):

The SX30 IS has a thread which is designed to hold a slim step-up ring to 67mm which Canon sells as an accessory. This lets you use 67mm thread. If you use smaller thread directly, it will ruin your photos taken near wide-angle.

Answer (score 2):

The SX30is doesn't have a thread for filters to screw directly onto the lens. You need the FA-DC67A adapter, which allows you to fit 67mm screw-on filters.

Comment: but yesterday i go to camera shop, the shopmen attached on that nikon original 52 mm uv filter....how it is?

Comment: Looking around in a little more depth, it seems a 52mm filter can be screwed on, but further 'into' the lens: if you look at the lens head-on, there are a series of concentric plastic rings around the outside, before you get to the glass proper. A 52mm filter can apparently fit into those somewhere. However, I suspect that there will be some vignetting at wide angles (i.e. when you have zoomed right back). Go back to the shop, get the guy to fit the 52mm filter and then use the camera at it's widest angle setting. Check you can't see the edges of the filter at the edge of the image.

Answer (score 1):

I just verified it does  has some ~52 mm threads but not quite. I tried some of my 52mm  macro lenses/adapters  and they kind fit, but not precisely as they do in real 52mm lenses.

Answer (score 1):

What the prior comment called threads are just concentric circles to hold the lens cap not a filter. They are not really threads which match real threads required for 52mm filters. If you use a 52mm filter, such as a UV to protect the front lens, it will not screw on properly.  It can be forced on but the stress on the lens itself while forcing the filter to "jump" threads cause cause damage.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a slim UV filter without any problems with edges in wide angles.

Comment: Could you provide a link to an example item that would work?

Answer (score 0):

This [Fotasy JJC RN-DC67A 67mm Filter Adapter + Lens Cap + UV filter kit](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004MLF4ZO) should work as a slim adapter for using 67mm lenses on the Canon Powershot SX30 IS (among others).

I just ordered one to use as a spare snap on adapter so I can have multiple filters ready to go. I am not sure on the quality of the filter/lens cap that comes with it but I have a nicer UV filter and cap I will use anyways. You can find some really nice 67mm lens sets on Amazon as well.